# Fit map to bounds exactly

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way to fit the map exactly to bounds? (or as close a possible).

For example, in this jsfiddle, even without padding the map leaves a lot of padding above and below the points:

http://jsfiddle.net/BC7q4/444/

```js
map.fitBounds(bounds);

$('#fit1').click(function(){ map.fitBounds(bounds); });
$('#fit2').click(function(){ map.fitBounds(bounds, {padding: [50, 50]}); });
```

I'm trying to fit a map as precisely as possible to a set of bounds that closely match the map shape without all the extra padding.

Setting a map's ne corner and sw corner would work as well, but I don't think that functionality exists.

Answer (score 14):

You are very probably looking for the map [`zoomSnap`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomsnap) option:

> Forces the map's zoom level to always be a multiple of this, particularly right after a `fitBounds()` or a pinch-zoom. By default, the zoom level snaps to the nearest integer; lower values (e.g. `0.5` or `0.1`) allow for greater granularity. A value of `0` means the zoom level will not be snapped after fitBounds or a pinch-zoom.

Because its default value is `1`, after your `fitBounds` the map will floor down the zoom value to the closest available integer value, hence possibly introducing more padding around your bounds.

By specifiying `zoomSnap: 0`, you ask the map not to snap the zoom value:

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
  zoomSnap: 0 // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomsnap
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 5);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var southWest = new L.LatLng(40.712, -74.227),
  northEast = new L.LatLng(40.774, -74.125),
  bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

L.marker([40.712, -74.227]).addTo(map);
L.marker([40.774, -74.125]).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds);

$('#fit1').click(function() {
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
$('#fit2').click(function() {
  map.fitBounds(bounds, {
    padding: [50, 50]
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<button id="fit1">fit without bounds</button>
<button id="fit2">fit with bounds</button>
<div id="map"></div>
```